# Laravel 5.2 exists validation cannot find column

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have wierd trouble during validating `request` in `controller`. I use `exists` validation rule. User is supposed to submit `integer`. This integer should exist as `id` in a single row of `user_courses` table. This row also should have column `user_id` equal to `158` - [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists).

**My validation rule**:

```
'course_id' => 'integer|exists: user_courses, id, user_id, 158'
```

**What I got instead**:

> PDOException in Connection.php line 333: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column ' id' in 'where clause'

**My Table**:

```
id, user_id, created_at, updated_at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in the spaces:

```
'course_id' => 'integer|exists: user_courses, id, user_id, 158' // incorrect

'course_id' => 'integer|exists:user_courses,id,user_id,158' // correct
```

Original code would confuse laravel to search for column names like this:

```
' user_courses'
```

Comment: thanks man I was looking for this same with the `unique` it was the dam space there